# Does 'SELECT FOR UPDATE' work in pg-promise task?

Tags: node.js, postgresql-9.5, pg-promise

I want to do `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`  to lock a row in a table so it can be updated in a atomic way, as concurrent request of the same type could happen.

I've been doing some testing but its not clear `FOR UPDATE` works in a `pg-promise.task`. I'm trying to avoid using a `pg-promise.tx` as that would require more logic and possibly recursion, both of which I want to avoid as the use case will be high throughput.

**Update:**
After more research and testing, I've found that using a `task` with `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` is giving me an unexpected result. Explanation of code below.

```
submitUserOnline:(pgdb, u_uuid, socketConnectionList, user_websock) =>{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
// pgdb.tx({mode} t => {
   pgdb.task( t => {
    return t.one('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uuid = $1', [u_uuid]
    .then(user =>{
// nothing happens here right now, but may in future, including for completeness. May cancel request based off some comparisons.
     return t.any('SELECT * FROM users_online WHERE user_uuid = $1 FOR UPDATE',[u_uuid]
     .then(result =>{
      if(result.length > 0){
        console.error('duplicate connection found ' + user_websock.uuid);
        if(socketConnectionList[result[0].web_sock_uuid] !== undefined){
          console.error('drop connection' + result[0].web_sock_uuid);
          socketConnectionList[result[0].web_sock_uuid].wsc.close(4020, 'USER_RECONN');
        }
        console.error('duplicate connection found - update next ' + user_websock.uuid);
        return t.none('UPDATE users_online SET web_sock_uuid = $1 WHERE user_uuid = $2', [user_websock, u_uuid])
        .then(res =>{
          console.error('UPDATE res: ' + res);
        })
        .catch(err =>{
          console.error('UPDATE err: ' + err);});

       }else{
         // not reached in test case
         console.error('no duplicate found ' + user_websock.uuid);
         return t.none(INSERT INTO  users_online.....ect ect
       }
      });
   })
   .then(res =>{
     console.error('>>>task/tx res: ' + res);
     resolve({msg: "OK"});
   })
   .catch(err =>{
     console.error('>>>task/tx err: ' + err);
     if(err.code ==== '40001'){// recursion for when called as 'tx'
       console.error('>>>task/tx err - call recurse');
       module.exports.submitUserOnline(pgdb, u_uuid, socketConnectionList, user_websock)
       .then(res =>{
         console.error('>>>task/tx err - call recurse - res ' + res);
         resolve({msg: "OK"});
        })
        .catch( err =>{
          console.error('>>>task/tx err - call recurse - err: ' + err);
          reject({msg:"FAILED"});
        });
     }
    });
  });
}
```

```
const mode = new TransactionMode({
    tiLevel: isolationLevel.serializable,
    readOnly: false,
    deferrable: true
});
```

`submitUserOnline` is called by a websocket handler. In my test case I have an 10 element array(same user_uuid) which triggers all client connections in a for loop. Basically its making the connections to the server websocket, that socket checks the `users_online` table for the specific user, if that user is already in the table, kill the stale connection and update the `web_sock_uuid` in the table, this is where the issues comes in(sometimes it works sometimes not, one run of 10 concurrent connections shows the issue). When the user row `web_sock_uuid` is `UPDATE`'ed, the other concurrent connections seem to block properly on the `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE(SLFU)`, when the `UPDATE` executes, `then()` doesnt always run before the next `SLFU` is released. This seems to present it self in the form of the pending `SLFU` returning the old `web_sock_uuid` of the row before the prior `UPDATE`. In one instance the same stale 'web_sock_uuid' was returned 4 times in a row.

If I switch from the `task` method to the `tx` method, which requires the recursive calling, the above code works as expected, although it does require many recersions.

Comment: Any question here should include what you have tried, and the problem you encountered. In the meantime, methods task and tx do not care what kind of queries you are executing inside.

Comment: @vitaly-t : glade to see this caught your eye, please see updated OP.

Comment: You should use [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor) to give you a clear pictures in terms of the connections and queries being executed. May be then you will spot an issue yourself ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've long since figured this out, but I forgot to post back at the time. **The solution for me was to use the `tx` method, with no mode options provided.** This gives the desired operation. Would explain it more, but the exact details have faded from my mind.

Comment: If details are pending, then please hold off on posting an answer until you have those details.

Comment: No details are pending.

Comment: @nunya07 If you care for it to be useful to other developers, then please make an effort and provide the details.

Comment: Ive bolded the answer. When I said details, those details would require paragraphs of explanation to fully explain, and are more of a blow by blow of the steps I took and the results to widdle away to something that worked.

Answer (score 0):

The `pg-promise` [`tasks`](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Task.html) are simply shared connections. They do not create transactions implicitly.

To use locks in Postgres, you need to create transactions, since all locks created in a transaction are released at the end of the transaction. If you do not create transactions explicitly, each query will be its own separate transaction.

Of course, you do not have to use the `tx` method. You could use `task`, and manage the transaction yourself.